# Looking for a Python chess engine

Tags: engines, python

I am looking for a Python chess engine package. It must be fully contained in Python, I don't want to download separate files for the engine itself and link them up somehow.

All I want it to be able to do is take a FEN and provide best move. It should obviously be a strong engine, at least 2500 rating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning scores for all possible moves from a chess engine](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/15723/returning-scores-for-all-possible-moves-from-a-chess-engine)

Comment: @Phonon I don't think it's a duplicate because the other answer uses Stockfish, which is not written in Python and so it is explicitly forbidden by this question.

Answer (score 3):

I have experience with only SunFish, but I doubt it's 2500+ level.

> http://talkchess.com/forum3/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=67025

This link should help you. If you're not happy with the folks at talkchess, you probably won't find a better answer anywhere else.

Comment: I doubt too. Maybe 2200 is closer to the actual level.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Sunfish is PyChess: http://pychess.org/ (or https://github.com/pychess/pychess)

It's stronger than sunfish (has 2100 bullet rating on lichess: https://lichess.org/@/PyChessBot ) and also allows playing chess variants, such as antichess or fisher random.

It has a lot more code than sunfish though, so pulling it out as a separate library takes a bit more work.
See also http://talkchess.com/forum3/viewtopic.php?t=67025