# Python-chess : how to get a list for the best engine moves

Tags: engines, programming, python

I am working on a simple cheat detection script to find if a user used one of the  top engine moves in a game, so I found this great python-chess library
Additionally, [I found this example](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/15723/returning-scores-for-all-possible-moves-from-a-chess-engine/15734#comment39098_15734) to getting the moves score. But that topic is an old version of the lib so I tried to update the script. However, I keep getting errors, and I don't know how to get the scores in the right way.

```
import asyncio
import chess
#import chess.uci
import chess.engine
import chess.pgn
import io
#Let's try our code with the starting position of chess:

fen = 'rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1'
board = chess.Board(fen)


#Now make sure you give the correct location for your stockfish engine file
#...in the line follows: e.g., /home/.../stockfish_6_x64


engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci('/home/shar/Desktop/cheat detect python/stockfish-10-linux/Linux/stockfish_10_x64')

if board.turn: print( 'White to move');
else: print( 'black to move');

for el in board.legal_moves:



    pgn = io.StringIO(board.san(el))

    thnwpgntofen = chess.pgn.read_game(pgn);
    nwinfo = engine.analysis(thnwpgntofen.board());



    print(nwinfo["score"])


    print("-------------------------");
```

I get this error after running my code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "prntengmv.py", line 37, in
>   
>       print(nwinfo["score"]) TypeError: 'SimpleAnalysisResult' object is not subscriptable

Comment: The updated version is added [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/15734/3594).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per: https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html#indefinite-or-infinite-analysis

`engine.analysis(board)` now returns an `AnalysisResult` object, which has the property `info` that you want.

So instead of:

```
nwinfo = engine.analysis(...)
print(nwinfo["score"])
```

You would loop over `info` in the `AnalysisResult`, and print the score property from each element:

```
with engine.analysis(...) as analysis:
    for info in analysis:
        print(info.get("score"))
```

However, your use case looks like it may benefit from [`engine.analyse`](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html#analysing-and-evaluating-a-position) more than `engine.analysis`.

Comment: thanks now the error gones but i getting a hundreds of outputs

Comment: This is because `engine.analysis` gives an indefinite analysis - i.e. the engine will keep analyzing forever. You can resolve this by setting some termination condition and exiting the loop, or you could use `engine.analyse` instead, which allows you to set a limit beforehand. Check the documentation link in my answer.

Comment: every time i run my script i getting a different score are for the same moves are that normal ?

Comment: Engines aren't wholly deterministic. As long as the scores are reasonable each time, it's probably correct.